# How to transfer integral to elliptic one

Tags: integration, elliptic-functions, elliptic-integrals

I have the following function 
$$E(\theta)=\int \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{(1-\alpha\cos\theta)(1+\beta\cos\theta)}},$$
I cannot find a suitable change of variable such that $E(\theta)$ converted into elliptic integral.

Comment: try $u = \tan(\theta / 2)$

Comment: @Youem: Such comment is not very constructive. What is actually achieved through such substitution?

Comment: Your claim is totaly correct. But my comment was just a hint to the OP.

Comment: after the $u = \tan\frac{\theta}{2}$ substitution, you need another one $\tan\psi = \sqrt{\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}}u$

Comment: This change of variable give me $\int\frac{u du}{\sqrt{[(1-a)+(1+a)u^2][(1+b)+(1-b)u^2]}}$